# Variants are not getting converted into object from JSON in Product class - firebase realtime database android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the product structure in firebase.

```
{
  "Available" : "1",
  "BrandID" : "26",
  "ProductID" : "244",
  "ProductImagePath" : "/images/palmolive/moisturising-deluxe.png",
  "ProductName" : "Moisturing Deluxe Shaving Cream",
  "SubCategoryID" : "23",
  "Variants" : {
    "244_26" : {
      "Available" : "1",
      "MRP" : "55.00",
      "SellPrice" : "54.00",
      "VariantID" : "26"
    },
    "244_42" : {
      "Available" : "1",
      "MRP" : "28.00",
      "SellPrice" : "27.00",
      "VariantID" : "42"
    }
  }
}
```

These are the model classes.

Product Class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Product {
    private String ProductID;
    private String BrandID;
    private String SubCategoryID;
    private String ProductName;
    private String ProductImagePath;
    private List<Variants> variants;
}
```

Variants Class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Variants {
    private String Available;
    private String MRP;
    private String SellPrice;
    private String VariantID;
}
```

This is the logic for converting JSON into objects

```
productsRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      Map<String, Product> products = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
      products.clear();
      if (Utility.getProductMap().size() == 0) {
          for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
              Product product = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Product.class);
              products.put(product.getProductID(), product);
          }
          Utility.setProductMap(products);
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
      // Failed to read value
      Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
      Utility.displayToast("Failed to read value." + error.toException());
  }
});
```

The problem is Variants are not getting converted into object. This check if (product.getVariants() == null) always returning true.

What is wrong in this logic?

Answer (score 0):

Your Java Class expects a `List<Variant>`, however, the `Variants` node in your database is a JSON Object not a JSON array, also, has a different name than the variable.

I think you should make your JSON `Variants` an array like this:

```
"Variants" : [
    "244_26" : {
      "Available" : "1",
      "MRP" : "55.00",
      "SellPrice" : "54.00",
      "VariantID" : "26"
    },
    "244_42" : {
      "Available" : "1",
      "MRP" : "28.00",
      "SellPrice" : "27.00",
      "VariantID" : "42"
    }
]
```

Now, `Variants` is a JSON array.
Also, you should change your `List<Variant> variant` variable to `List<Variant> Variant`, because object mapping is case-sensetive.

**Update:**

accepting the fact that you can't change your database structure, this might get a little harder, now inside your loop first thing you do is get the `Variants` list first, this can be done by iterating over the children of each product to find the `Variants` node, when you have it, iterate over it's children mapping them to `Variant` objects.

Code explanation: add another loop for each child DataSnapShot of each product (representing your product attributes) and when you reach the `Variants` node, iterate over it's children mapping them to `Variant` objects, then add them to your `variants` list, and then set the list to the `Product` object.

This is the only way I could think of getting the data out of this database without changing it's structure.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I corrected the name. Can you please help what other changes i need to do in class for above JSON data format to parse properly.

Comment: edited, try it and tell me if there still an issue, hopefully not :)

Comment: I don't have control to change JSON data format. i can make the changes in class only. what changes needs to be done in class to get it parsed?